# How do I hide or remove message after it has been displayed for a certain amount of time?

Tags: javascript, html, django

html:

```
{% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
        <div class="message">{{ message }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

js:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.message').fadeOut('slow');
        }, 2000);
    })
</script>
```

Here is my html and javascript. Right now the script does nothing to my message and it just stays on the page.

I have tried moving the div container outside the for loop and if statement but nothing works.

Is there a way around this or an alternate method?

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: From what I can see, you are missing a `)` at the last JavaScript line. Could that be it?

Comment: No error messages. The message just doesn't disappear. Fixed the ) issue, still does not work

Comment: Should work. Check the html source in your browser to see how your `message` div is styled and if your javascript is at the right spot (you can even set a breakpoint on the line `$('.message').fadeOut();` to see if it's triggered).